# How is the heap size of my JVM set for a docker spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jvm, heap-memory

I've never set the heap size of my docker image.

```
root@0f94b4ca1efb:/# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
   size_t ErgoHeapSizeLimit                        = 0                                         {product} {default}
   size_t HeapSizePerGCThread                      = 43620760                                  {product} {default}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 33554432                                  {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t LargePageHeapSizeThreshold               = 134217728                                 {product} {default}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 513802240                                 {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5825164                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122916538                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122916538                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
```

but I can see that in the image, the max heap size is 513M. So it's being calculated somehow. How do I set it myself if I want to increase it?

I've tried doing this

```
docker run -d --name devServer -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1g" -p 8080:8080 efd2e03a-8b5f-402a-8222-c8953e9f16aa /bin/bash
```

but it has no effect

Comment: This may answer your question: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/

Comment: Which version of JDK you're using?  If you're using JDK >=10 then memory limits are automatically recognized and enforced.  https://www.docker.com/blog/improved-docker-container-integration-with-java-10/

Answer (score 0):

The JVM automatically configures heap size according to the spec of the machine it is running on, the below article details.

https://www.atamanroman.dev/articles/jvm-memory-settings-container-environment/